# Cron prestashop module import stock

Tags: ubuntu, prestashop

I have a syncbyref module that allows me to import product stocks but when I run the cron with the command php or with the link that is given by syncbyref I have a error "Forbiden access"

I put the file cron.php module in 777 but I have the same problem. What is the right solution to solve this problem of law? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not having much information about your script I can only guess.

Is the script located within the modules/syncbyref directory of your Prestashop root directory?

If so, check if the file owner/group is the same of the owner of the other PS files.